# Scalar CPU vs Vector GPU vs Matrix AI vs Spatial FPGA

Tags: gpu, cpu, intel, spatial, fpga

> "... breadth of architectures span scalar (CPU), vector (GPU), matrix (AI) and spatial (FPGA)"

I've not heard CPUs vs GPUs described as scalar vs vector. Moreover AI described as an architecture (yes, definitely large matrices are needed for ML - but what does a matrix architecture mean - and aren't GPUs like the NVIDIA Titans often used to accelerate ML anyway) or FPGA described as a spatial architecture (spatial in what sense - not 3D AR/VR/XR spatial computing right?)

Can someone explain what is meant in such a statement ([source](https://newsroom.intel.com/news/intels-one-api-project-delivers-unified-programming-model-across-diverse-architectures/#gs.h2mmxh))?

Answer (score 3):

- CPUs are scalar: Every cycle, 1 instruction operates on 1 word of data.
- GPUs are vector: Every cycle, 1 instruction operates on many words of data.
- Matrix: Every cycle, 1 instruction multiplies matrices (typically small matrices such as 2x4 * 4x2 to yield an output matrix of size 2x2).
- Spatial architectures: In contrast to traditional architectures (CPU/GPU) where instructions flow through a pipe, here data flows through a grid of processing elements.

Modern CPUs have some vector capability (AVX), and possibly specialized matrix processing HW (Intel Nervana). Modern GPUs, in addition to being traditional vector processors, also have baked in specialized matrix processing HW (NVIDIA Volta/Turing).